# Office Web Apps and WOPI

Tags: c#, ms-office, ms-wopi

We have Office Web Apps and WOPI working and can load a powerpoint file and edit it.

However getting edit working for Word require implementing Cobalt or FSSHTTP/FSSHTTPB protocol?

The user here has kindly provided most of the code for everything([Can I just use Office Web Apps Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065029/can-i-just-use-office-web-apps-server))

Has anybody implemented a Cobalt or FSSHTTP/FSSHTTPB protocol within this context?

Comment: have you get a solution now? i am so frustrated with the same problem

Comment: @Marx I'm afraid not. Didn't manage to get editing of Word documents working

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825224/how-to-implement-ms-fsshttp-for-editing-word-with-wopi-host-on-c-sharp-and-wopi for a commercial implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could start by grabbing a cobalt assembly from the Office Web Apps machine, I think its called Microsoft.Cobalt.dll.. It should help you to decipher the messages. I am trying to get back to work on this proof-of-concept. If I get it to work I'll post a quick reference here. But the documentation sucks, I have to intercept the messages between the sharepoint and office web apps to make sense of them.

Comment: thank you. Appears we are doing the same thing. I'm just a bit further behind :) . Any link to the documentation?

Comment: the FSSHTTP/FSSHTTPB way seems to have more documentation. I'm coming from Java background too and trying to get this going for a prototype.

Comment: doesn't seem we can just do edit without implementing the whole coauth features...http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appsforoffice/thread/e6322139-421b-473e-aaed-d9693f989360

Comment: well I can decode the objects, its just I don't understand what they mean.

Comment: we managed to get the request by giving all the required true values in the json. now just need to fire response in soap and see what happens after that

Comment: @topcat3 This guy describes a little the cobalt protocol. Also check his testing framework, it includes some interesting code snippets. 

[http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/default.aspx)

Comment: any joy progressing with this? i've hit a brick wall. microsoft sent the xml schemas but theres no example code and very hard to work out

Comment: I've just joined this battle, attempting to implement FSSHTTP. I'm using PHP, but willing to change languages if necessary. Have you guys managed to get anywhere? The WOPI App Server is sending me a SOAP request for "RequestVersion" but I don't know how to generate a response.

Comment: @Mark We basically gave up. Microsoft have sample code but were unwilling to share it probably for good reason. We obviously started to look down the SharePoint route or to plug just client office in a browser. Good luck with it

Comment: Just updating people on some progress: https://github.com/thebitllc/WopiBasicEditor (does require CobaltCore assembly)

Answer (score 5):

I write a Wopi Host demo.
With Cobalt(FSSHTTPB/D) support for Office Web Apps. 
Support DOCX Editing, and also PPTX,XLSX.
Requires Microsoft.CobaltCore.dll

https://github.com/marx-yu/WopiHost

thanks thebitllc's great work

Comment: Hi @Marx Yu, please help me testing your WopiHost git project, I have configured your project in VS but couldn't understand how to use Office online 2016(preview) server as a client. I have office 2016 in my machine and office 365 account, I am using Windows 10 operating system and created a folder C:\wopi-docs\ with few office files.

Please let me know what you mean by Office online 2016 server (client) and how to integrate it with your WopiHost project (host).

Answer (score 0):

As of February 13, 2015 it seems the WOPI protocol now allows the server to specify whether it supports co-authoring of a given file in the CheckFileInfo endpoint response. So you can avoid the nastiness of the Cobalt implementation.