# How to implement MS-FSSHTTP for editing Word with WOPI host on C# and WOPI client is OWA

Tags: c#, fsshttp, ms-wopi

I am implementing MS-WOPI host with MS-WOPI  client being Office Web Apps. I want to provide Word editing functionality and need to implement MS-FSSHTTP protocol.

I read the documentation [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd943623(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd943623%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and

I also tried to fined some examples, but didn't get the success.

Could someone provide a simple example of MS-FSSHTTP implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation using CobaltCore. Pretty much a combination of my answers about WOPI/FSSHTTP on this website in one project.

https://github.com/thebitllc/WopiBasicEditor

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for the impossible.  There is no such thing as a simple fsshttp server.  Look at the videos on MSDN from conferences where they've discussed it.  The fsshttp team estimates it will take over a year to properly build out a protocol server.  It is not a project for the faint of heart.

Comment: Seems like using CobaltCore assembly will simplify this project. I try to implement ExecuteCellStorageRequest operation using Cobalt API, but this assembly still doesn't public and I cannot find any open documentation.